# Steam won't start - integer parameter out of range for operation

Tags: graphics, steam

Yesterday, I wanted to open Steam, but it didn't open. After some digging, I discovered the error:

`ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2018-03-28 08:21:21] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)`

After reinstall steam (both from the Ubuntu repos and from steampowered.com) I saw several people suggesting things with runtime (but I couldn't find the Steam Runtime in my reinstall), and deleting libstdc++.so.6. This all didn't work for me.

Strange thing is, I reckon it stopped working when I installed the `nvidia-390` driver, but I can't install the driver that worked for me because apt always install `nvidia-390`. My third screen, connected to my Intel HD Graphics, also stopped working with this driver. So, how do I get Steam working?

Hardware:
CPU: Intel Core i5 6400
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060
Software:
Ubuntu 17.10 with KDE & SDDM installed (though it's not Kubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify your nvidia drivers are properly installed issue this in a terminal

```
nvidia-smi
```

which should give you output similar to

```
Tue May 23 13:18:34 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    292MiB /  2002MiB |     21%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1583    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             175MiB |
|    0      3445    G   /usr/bin/compiz                                115MiB |
|    0      6737    G   /home/stens/src/firefox/firefox                  1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

whereas when nvidia drivers are in an inconsistent state you will see this

```
nvidia-smi

Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

which is probably the case here ... I suggest you reinstall the drivers

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to mention I switched to Solus. Even though that's the case, I highly doubt it was anything else than the drivers. I'll mark this anwser as the solution, even though I had difficulties reinstalling the driver.